# Python - Writing zips of a specific size is very unreliable

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I'm attempting to write a script in python that will zip up a directory.  I want to zip files until the zip file is around 500MB, then start a new zip, until all the files have been zipped.  The rules then look like:

```
1) Walks a directory finding all files (using os.walk)
2) Begin writing said files to a zip until the zip is ~500MB
3) Once I've reached that limit, start a new zip following same rules (~500MB limit)
4) End result being N zips all around ~500MB or less
```

My code right now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import math as m

current_dir = os.getcwd()
deal_name = current_dir.split("/")[-1:][0]
deal_folder = f'{current_dir}/{deal_name}'
deal_folder_exists = os.path.isdir(deal_folder)
file_paths = []
vol = 1
ZIP_MAX_SIZE = 500

if not deal_folder_exists:
    print(f'Can not find deal folder: {deal_folder}')
    raise Exception('Missing Deal Folder')

# Generate a list of all files to be written to zip
for root, directories, files in os.walk(deal_folder):
    if files:
        # We have files to add to the zip
        for file in files:
            file_paths.append(f'.{root.replace(deal_folder, "")}/{file}')

# Change into the deal folder
os.chdir(deal_folder)

# writing files to a zipfile
deal_zip_path = f'../{deal_name}-vol{vol}.zip'
deal_zip = ZipFile(deal_zip_path, 'w')

# Just a dict for keepin track of the end size of each zip
zip_data = {deal_zip_path: 0}

# Begin looping over the files, and writing the files to the zip
for file in file_paths:
    deal_zip.write(file)
    size = round(sum([info.file_size for info in deal_zip.infolist()]) / 1e+6)

    # Track the current size
    zip_data[deal_zip_path] = size

    # If the current size exceeds the max, bump the vol var and start a new zip
    if size > ZIP_MAX_SIZE:
        deal_zip.close()
        vol += 1
        deal_zip_path = f'../{deal_name}-vol{vol}.zip'
        deal_zip = ZipFile(deal_zip_path, 'w')

# Close the final zip
deal_zip.close()

# Log the deets
print(zip_data)
print('All files zipped successfully!')
```

The `zip_data` print looks like this:

```
{
    '../magical-holiday-goodies-vol1.zip': 542, 
    '../magical-holiday-goodies-vol2.zip': 503, 
    '../magical-holiday-goodies-vol3.zip': 505, 
    '../magical-holiday-goodies-vol4.zip': 545, 
    # sometime later
    '../magical-holiday-goodies-vol15.zip': 309
}
```

So it appears that the script is doing exactly what it should be doing.  However, the end results of the zip are super unpredictable.  For instance, vol1.zip above says it should be 542MB, when in reality I get:

[image: Note the 12.2 MB zip...]

Any idea why my logging shows the correct file sizes, when in reality the resulting zip sizes are all over the place?

Comment: `info.file_size` is `Size of the uncompressed file` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects). I think you want `info.compress_size`.

Comment: Ah, so that does help a bit, but my zips are still way off.  It went from 12.2MB to 25MB, still nowhere near the 500MB limit.  The logging says that the zip should be 542MB.  Thank you for the quick response @quamrana!

Comment: To note, I just ran it again, and my first zip was 9MB, so it's not even repeatable the same every time.  I think I'm missing some fundamentals on how writing the zips works, or maybe I'm dealing with some kind of race condition.  Some of my zips do end up around the 500MB limit (maybe 5 of 15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `ZipFile` is just storing the files.

Replace the constructor call with: `deal_zip = ZipFile(deal_zip_path, 'w', compression = ZIP_DEFLATED)`

Also: `from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED`

Comment: Tried this too, now all of the resulting zips are in the 5-10MB range, and the script takes much longer to run.  I'm a bit baffled! Super appreciate you taking the time to help! Thank you!

Comment: I did add a `deal_zip.close()` before checking the size, and then if the size isn't exceeded reopen it with `ZipFile(deal_file_path, 'a')` and now the first few zips are in the 30MB size, and the rest are (about 15 of them) are in the 500-600MB size, so that seems to be getting me closer.

Comment: So, in what might be some MacOS weirdness, when I moved the resulting zips to a new folder for testing the extractions, finder now reports all zips around the 500MB limit, which means it's working as expected.  No idea how or why, but I think you've helped me solve this one!  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, this is super weird, Finder is giving me false values for the zip sizes.  Terminal is showing me things are right on the money.